# Objects with Mesh lambert material not being generated while rendering graphics with three.js

Tags: three.js

Well I just started learning three.js which is totally totally totally new to me. So I am writing these series of hello world kinda scrips.Well I wrote the script below to generate a cube with MeshBasicMaterial (Well this is just an exact copy of a tutorial given in a blog)

```
        var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 640/340, 0.1, 1000); 
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 

        renderer.setSize(640, 340); 
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(1,1,1); 
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xD43001});
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); 


        scene.add(cube); 
        camera.position.z = 5; 

        var render = function (){

                requestAnimationFrame(render); 

                cube.rotation.x += 0.1; 
                cube.rotation.y += 0.1; 

                renderer.render(scene, camera); 

            };

            render();
```

The script above generates a cube which rotates continuously now when I change the material of the cube from

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xD43001});
```

to

```
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xD43001});
```

nothing gets displayed. WHat exctly am I missing?

UPDATE

So i had to add a light source to display an object made out of mesh lambert material.When I added a point light the object got displayed.

Answer (score 5):

This is because MeshBasicMaterial does not react to lighting but has a constant colour.

A MeshLambertMaterial however, **does** react to lighting, so without light, you cannot see it! The same goes for MeshPhongMaterial.

Comment: MeshLambertMaterial depends on light, where as MeshPhongMaterial depends both on light as well as camera